# Complement of $(a+b)^*aba$ intuitively

Tags: formal-languages, automata

How would you come up intuitively with a complement of the language expressed by the following regular expression: $(a + b)^*aba$?

Not intuitively, I would convert it to DFA, then get the complement out of the DFA, then convert the result to a regular expression through state elimination for example.

If I try to come up with an intuitive complement, I would say that it's $(a+b)^*abb$, but I can't verify.

Comment: What is $(a+b)$? Is it the set $\{a,b\}$, and the star on it collects all words of length zero, one, two... in $a,b$? Are $a,b$ words or atomic symbols of the (not) given language? If $a,b$ are (the only) letters of the language, the complement is obviously the set of all words of length $\le 2$ together with all words of length $3$ not terminating in $aba$, so there are the other $2^3-1$ possible terminals of length three for this latter part.

Comment: What you have said is already obvious, but I wanted the real regular expression :D

Comment: Your question is different, has something to do with "intuition", as it stays a lot of stuff is undefined, this was the reason for the comment, and the support for the question is for the non-intuitive approach. The title also contains the "intuitive" direction. Mathematically, it is unclear what kind of answer is needed / wanted. But **first** just make clear what are $a,b$, and if the **plus** in $(a+b)$ stays for $a^+b$, or for the set with two letters $a,b$.

Comment: Ok, $(a+b)^*$ is the set of all words. $a$ and $b$ are the alphabets, and the only ones.

Comment: For a solution by inspection, I would expect the complement to be something like $[(a|b)^*(b|aa|bba)]|ba|a|\varepsilon$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler that makes sense, but a lengthy one for sure.